# C++ Builder Lifetime of Static Class Property/Variable of a dynamicly created form?

Tags: c++builder

I have a `TSettingsForm` that has a `static String` member variable (not a pointer).  That form is dynamically created and destroyed as needed.

On the constructor of my `TMainForm` I set the `TSettingsForm` static string member variable a string value that persists though-out use of the program except on the `TMainForm::FormDestroy` where that static String is empty/NULL.   I would expect the static member variables should live past the `FormDestroy`.

I searched for anyplace that value would change and set break points but found nothing unexpected.  So I wonder why C++ Builder is zeroing that out before the application ends?  Is there something I'm missing?

Also, is there a data change based break-point available in C++ Builder like there is in Visual Studio?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static objects exist until the program is shutting down. They are destroyed after `main()`/`WinMain()` has exited.

By default, any object that is owned by the global `TApplication` object, *such as the main `TForm`*, is not destroyed until `TApplication` itself is destroyed, which happens after `main()`/`WinMain()` has exited.

So, you end up with a race condition in the cleanup order of global objects. And worse, that cleanup is being handled by different frameworks, as `TApplication` is managed by the Delphi runtime, whereas your static member is managed by the C++ runtime.

The value of the static member is not simply being zeroed out, the `String` object itself has been destroyed (and its destructor destroyed the character data it was holding). So, you have *undefined behavior* when you are trying to access that member during app cleanup.

That being said, you should not be using the `TForm::OnDestroy` (or `OnCreate`) event in C++ to begin with. They are Delphi idioms that can cause *undefined behavior* in C++, as Delphi and C++ use different object creation/cleanup semantics. The `OnDestroy` event *can* occur after your C++ destructor (and the `OnCreate` event *can* occur before your C++ constructor). So, in C++, always use your `TForm`'s actual destructor (and constructor) instead.

And yes, C++Builder has the ability to set breakpoints on memory address accesses and data changes. See Embarcadero's documentation for details:

[Setting and Modifying Breakpoints](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_and_Modifying_Breakpoints)

Comment: So to summarize what you're saying is the actual `TMainForm` is destroyed prior to `OnDestroy()` being called.  I wouldn't have expected that, but understand what you are saying.

Comment: I said that *could* happen. You will have to debug the code to see if that is *actually* happening. But, it is clear from your description that the static `String` member is being destroyed before the `OnDestroy` event is called. The destruction of the `String` has nothing to do with the destruction of the `TMainForm`, as they are not linked together. Obviously, that would be different if the `String` weren't static.